# Every diffeomorphism which is an isometry is also conformal

Tags: differential-geometry, conformal-geometry, isometry

I have the next definition of a conformal map:

> A diffeomorphism $f:S_1\to S_2$ between two surfaces is said to be conformal if for any two curves $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ in $S_1$ intersecting in a point $P$, the angle between the two curves in the point $P$ is equal to the angle between the the curves $f\circ\gamma_1$ y $f\circ\gamma_2$ in the point $f(P)$.

I'm trying to prove that every isometric diffeomorphism is conformal. What I want to show is that $$\frac{f(x)\cdot f(y)}{\|f(x)\|\|f(y)\|}=\frac{x\cdot y}{\|x\|\|y\|}$$ but I don't know where to start from. So I would apreciate some hints.

Comment: Note that your notation isn't quite right: $f(x) , f(y) \in S_2$, so what is $f(x) \cdot f(y)$?

Comment: An isometry preserves the inner product at each tangent space. Therefore it will preserve the inner product between the tangent vectors at the intersection of the curves.

Comment: @JohnMa $S_1$ and $S_2$ are both surfaces embbeded in some euclidean space, so i refer to the standard inner product.

Comment: Well, then using this definition, isometry are not necessary conformal (But I think you might got the wrong definition) @JosePaternina

Comment: @JohnMa maybe my approach is not the correct one.

Comment: @user40276 do you have any reference or proof of that statement? ("isometry preserves the inner product at each tangent space")

Comment: @JosePaternina It's a straightforward application of the definition if you defines an isometry as a smooth function $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ such that $df_p: T_p X \longrightarrow T_{f(p)} Y$ preserves the metric at each point $p \in X$. If you're working inside the euclidean space your metric is given as ${g_p}|_{T_pS}$ where $g= \sum_i {dx^i}^2$ and $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an embedded submanifold and $p \in S$

Answer (score 1):

Let, $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two surfaces with surface patches $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ respectively.

A diffeomorphism $f:S_1\rightarrow  S_2$ is said to be a conformal iff the First fundamental form of $\sigma_1$ of $S_1$ and $\sigma_2=f\circ\sigma_1$ of $S_2$ are proportional.

If $f$ is a local isometry then the First fundamental form of $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are the same as the first Fundamental form represents the length of the curve, and hence they are proportional consequently $f$ is conformal.

Hope this works.